# Most efficient way of writing multi-select data to a SQL Server backend

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, code-behind, multi-select

I've got a multi-select listbox in an ASP.Net front end using C#.  I want to store my data to a SQL Server table.

Do I parse out the data in the code-behind and send the data by looping through an INSERT INTO statement from C#?  Or is it more efficient to send a comma-delimited string to the SQL Server, use a table-valued function and then insert the data into the table on that end?

If it's the former, can anyone provide sample code if my multi-select field is called "MatchGender", I'm using a UserID and the table it's being inserted into is called tblMatches?  I'm not sure of the C# code necessary to loop through all selected values in a multi-select listbox.

Comment: You should also look into table valued parameters: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: A table valued parameter is the way to go. What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: Well, first I wasn't sure which was more efficient, and then I'm having trouble because I can't pre-build a table.  This query may possibly be run by over 1,000 people simultaneously, so I'm having trouble creating a solution that takes that into consideration.

Comment: Again, use a table valued parameter. [it's the most efficient way to pass array like structures to Sql server 2008 or higher.](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html)